# Python - How do I compare an element in a list against other elements in the same list

Tags: python, list, loops

For e.g.

```
lst = [['A', 300, 20], ['B', 235, 10], ['C', 274, 40], ['D', 290, 12]]
```

Lets just say I want to compare the 2nd element (index 1) of each list and find the highest. I only know how to compare the first list with the next list and so on. Which means I'm not comparing the list with the other lists. How do I start with the first list, compare with the other lists, then move onto the second list and compare with the other lists including the first one etc. So that each list has been compared with the others instead of just looking at the next one. I want to see which list dominates the rest, so for this instance I want to add 'True' to the end of the list.

Output: ['A', 300, 20, True]

Comment: Please update your question with the output you require.

Comment: A simple nested loop should help you do the trick

Comment: `max([x[1] for x in lst])`

Comment: To get sublist with max 2nd value: `max(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])` which returns ['A', 300, 20] in this case.

Comment: @quamrana I have updated it

Comment: Finding the maximum does not have to be O(n^2)